# Accessibility identifiers stopped finding elements used for UI testing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I've set up accessibility identifiers in the storyboard. These were working. However, I enabled accessibility on more views and now none of the elements can be found using the accessibility identifiers.

But, I can still find elements using the code generated by the record function.

Here's how I'm finding the elements:

```
XCUIApplication().buttons["loginButton"] //loginButton is the accessibility identifier
```

Here's how that same button is found using the recorder:

```
XCUIApplication().children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: 
.other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: 
.other).element.children(matching: .other).element.tap()
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
No matches found for *typeOfElement*
```

I haven't been able to find an applicable solution online so far.

**My question a nutshell:** Why can't I get a reference to elements using the accessibility identifiers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to this is that when you make a view accessible you also make all of its subviews inaccessible. Therefore, because I made the superview(s) of the views that I was accessing accessible I could no longer access those subviews. This means that to make the subviews accessible again I had to the disable the superview's accessibility property.